# Can my question be taken off Hold now?

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, closed-questions

I have a question that I believe is now clear.  Can it be re-opened or can you explain what more I can do to make it fit the guidelines?

[Are there any specific laws and consequences for claiming to be God?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69809/are-there-any-specific-laws-and-consequences-for-claiming-to-be-god)

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Done.

For future reference, if a question is closed and you thereafter edit it, [it will appear on the reopen queue](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/161390), so you don't need to request reopening. And if you choose to request reopening anyway, and it was closed by a moderator (someone with a "♦" after his username) or a badgeholder (so the closure notice will show the name of a tag after the closer's username), then [you can attract his attention in a comment on the question](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019), so you don't need to post here on Meta.

But Meta's fine, too.

Comment: In this case it doesn't apply, but I'm about 95% sure that the part about edits sending a post to the reopen queue only applies to questions that are on hold, not ones that rolled over to being closed.  If you edit an *old* question to try to reopen it, it's a good idea to raise it somewhere (chat, meta, ping to the close-voter as you mentioned, etc).